# How to pass data to kthread_run

Tags: c, multithreading, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I'm try to make simple kernel module with multithreading.
So I'm using linux/kthread.h, kernel v. 5.2.11

Problem: I can't passing the char array into thread: Segmentation fault.

That's what I'm doing:

```
typedef struct {
    int num; 
    char origin[MAXSTR]; //part of input for current thread
    struct completion wait_for_thread;      //completion struct
} kthread_arg;
```

Then:

```
struct task_struct *task;
static kthread_arg kta_first_thread;
kta_first_thread.num = 1;
strncpy(kta_first_thread.origin, dat1, MAXSTR );

//Here I have normal char array 'origin'
init_completion(&kta_first_thread.wait_for_thread);
task = kthread_run(&thread_function, (void*)&kta_first_thread, "one");
```

And after that I have the error. Moreover, if you remove the array from struct, then everything works.
I'm sure doing something wrong?

Comment: "And after that I have the error." - Show that error.

Comment: The code you have posted looks OK (assuming `dat1` is valid).

Comment: Yep, dat1 is valid. My error is Segmentation fault and kernel is panic. I think this is due to the array size of 6.25 Mb (MAXSTR = 50000000)

Comment: Why are you not allocating it on the heap?

Comment: Allocating 6MB in the **stack** is not a good idea in any case. If you want more detailed help, then you need to provide more details in the question. Currently you have only a small piece of code, which probably doesn't cause an error **by itself**, and a "segmentation fault" error which helps a little. Ideally, for being able to help you with your code we want an [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The args passed to kernel_run must be kmalloced, your args is in stack. I have met the same problem, your code should like this:

```
struct your_struct* test=NULL;
struct task_struct* t=NULL;
test=(struct your_struct*)kmalloc(sizeof(struct your_struct),GFP_KERNEL);
t=kthread_run(your_function,(void*)test,name);
```